# Appending the values in child nodes of an Xpath using oracle sql

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, append

I am having a problem with an xml format as belows

```
<text>
       <value>ABC</value>
       <value>CDE</value>
       <value>EFG</value>
</text>
```

How can I append the child node values?(the ones inside value tag) into a single string using oracle sql inorder for me to store in single field of the database table. The number of child nodes can vary(as above one has 3 and the other 2).

At last I need to have the values ABCCDEEFG as a single string together after executing the oracle sql query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using combination of `EXTRACT()` and `REPLACE()` functions in order to extract such a string as

```
SELECT REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                       EXTRACT(xmlData, '/text/value'), 
               '</value>'),
       '<value>') AS "Result String"
  FROM t

Result String
-------------
ABCCDEEFG
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=67bcb0c976227608ee37cbe9109049b0)</kbd>

where `REPLACE()`(*the first one*) function converts the extracted value of `XMLType` to `VARCHAR` type

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I want to keep a space between the 3 words what needs to be done? I mean to get something like ABC CDE EFG

Comment: you're welcome just as simple as a leaving a whitespace as the 3rd argument for the inner `REPLACE()` such as `REPLACE(EXTRACT(xmlData, '/text/value'),'</value>',' ')`  [-->](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9cdce7519a2cb550725c92601c88dd74)

Comment: Wow fantastic. By the way  If I dont have the parent tags(here it is <text>) How should I change it? I mean only if 3 value tags were there?   I tried this but gives an error "extra data after end of document"           
 WITH t(XMLData) AS
(
 SELECT XMLType('
                 <value>ABC</value>
                 <value>CDE</value>
                 <value>EFG</value>
                 ') 
   FROM dual
)
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(EXTRACT(xmlData, '/value'),'</value>'),'<value>') 
    AS "Result String"
  FROM t

Comment: @Amal : Get rid of `XMLType` conversion for this case, since it's not valid for `XMLType` conversion [-->](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9c2cdf4c53f2d1545415d789622a2a97)

Comment: wow your the best Oracle developer I have ever met. Thanks alot. I was confused with these xml stuff since there are very less examples even there is lot of documentation

Comment: One last thing I want to know whether is actually put line breaks in the replace function so that I can get the 3 words into 3 lines instead of the space?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ecf78353850c5037bf475e8feaca90c7) ? @Amal

Comment: yep this is it :). Its amazing without using XML operations you do these stuff. Appreciate your support. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

The [`EXTRACT` XML function is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-XML.html) and you should use one of the replacements such as `XMLQUERY` or `XMLTABLE`:

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY( 'string-join(/text/value/text()," ")' PASSING xml RETURNING CONTENT ) AS items
FROM   table_name
```

or

```sql
SELECT items
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT LISTAGG( value, ' ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY rownum)
                  AS items
         FROM   XMLTABLE(
                  '/text/value'
                  PASSING t.xml
                  COLUMNS
                    value VARCHAR2(20) PATH '.'
                )
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( xml ) AS
 SELECT XMLType('<text><value>ABC</value><value>CDE</value><value>EFG</value></text>') FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> | ITEMS       |
> | :---------- |
> | ABC CDE EFG |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c9c02c2d25cbd3d882964b62003a2ba)*